# Set object in Django @schema(AutoSchema(manual_fields=

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working in a django rest api that recieves an object in an endpoint.

Some of the object attributes are required some are not.

I want to show this in the documentation, but i don't know how to show the object with manual fields.

Right now i have just the name of the object like:

```
@schema(AutoSchema(manual_fields=[
        coreapi.Field("node", required=True, location="query", description="Node Object")        
    ]))
```

This is shown in the documentation like this:

[image: django documentation]

Answer (score 0):

Use coreschema to set the description.

```
from rest_framework.compat import coreschema

coreapi.Field(
    name=name, required=required, location=location, 
    schema=coreschema.String(title=name, description=description)
)
```